# Why Authorization element in web.config doesn't work with OWIN?

Tags: asp.net, iis, authorization, owin, azure-active-directory

- I have created web form application that uses OWIN and Azure AD for authentication as described [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect) or [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapp-dotnet/)

  - I host this application in IIS under Default Web Site so i can access it as http://localhost
  - Then i added following configuration so that anonymous user cant access resources, except the starting page, ie. default.aspx

    ```
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />     
    </authorization>
    <location path="Default.aspx">
        <system.web>
           <authorization>
              <allow users="*" />
           </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    ```
- Everything is working fine at this point, and user gets authenticated on Azure site and redirected to my application. I see HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is true

  - then in IIS i created new application (not virtual directory) under Default Web Site, and point it to the physical location which has images. I name the child application "images"
  - Now AFTER authentication, when i try to access http://localhost/images/image1.jpg i get error

> Error message 401.2.:
>   Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server
>   configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory
>   or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication
>   methods enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's
>   administrator for additional assistance.

Why the authentication is not propagated to child application?

The application is pool is running under windows account which is adminsitartor on that machine. I am using Windows 10 and IIS version 10.0.10586.0 nad VS 2013 Update 5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612486/owin-iis-throws-access-denied-for-authenticated-user-while-accessing-child-appl/35662881#35662881

Comment: I have answered my question here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612486/owin-iis-throws-access-denied-for-authenticated-user-while-accessing-child-appl/35662881#35662881